# Nested generic collections: How to implement reference from item to container?

Tags: c#, generics, collections, nested

While implementing a design using nested generic collections, I stumbled across those  limitations apparently caused by C#'s invariant Generics:

```
Cannot convert from 'Collection<subtype of T> to 'Collection<T>'
```

That means, the following will not work, apparently due to the invariance of Generics:

```
class Outer<TInner, TInnerItem> where TInner : Inner<TInnerItem>
{
    public void Add(TInner item)
    {
        item.Outer = this; // ERROR:
            // Cannot implicitly convert from Outer<TInner, TInnerItem> 
            // to Outer<Inner<TInnerItem>, TInnerItem>
    }
}

class Inner<TInnerItem> : ICollection<TInnerItem>
{
    Outer<Inner<TInnerItem>, TInnerItem> _outer;

    public Outer<Inner<TInnerItem>, TInnerItem> Outer
    {
        set { _outer = value; }
    }
}
```

(In the actual code, both `Inner<>` and `Outer<>` implement `ICollection<>`.)

I need the `Inner<>` objects to have a reference to its container collection in order to access some of its data.

How would you implement these nested collections, preferably using a generic approach as outlined above? How would you set the reference to the container collection in the `Inner<>` class?

Cheers!

Comment: I can't wrap my head around your classes. If you give them more distinct names, maybe I can try to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introducing a (possibly abstract) base class which is not dependant on TInner may help you:

```
abstract class OuterBase<TInnerItem>
{
}

class Outer<TInner, TInnerItem> : OuterBase<TInnerItem> where TInner : Inner<TInnerItem>
{
    public void Add(TInner item)
    {
        item.Outer = this; // Compiles
    }
}

class Inner<TInnerItem> : ICollection<TInnerItem>
{
    OuterBase<TInnerItem> _outer;

    public OuterBase<TInnerItem> Outer
    {
        set { _outer = value; }
    }
}
```

Or wait for C# 4.0, which introduces co/contra-variant generic interfaces.

Comment: For my specific problem, in the end, I chose this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The language can't let you convert from Collection<subtype of T> to Collection<T>

Let me explain why.

Imagine you have a Collection<subT> and cast it to Collection<T>. That's ok, since subT inherits from T.

When you retrieve an object from `collection_of_T`, you're assured that it's ok.

Later, add a `T` object to `collection_of_T`. Now you have, in `collection_of_subT` an object which is not a `subT`. Whoops.

In order to achieve what you want, you must create a new Collection alltogether.

```
Collection<T> collection_of_T = new Collection<T>(collection_of_subT);
```

Which probably is not good for you. Do you really need the `TInner` generic argument in the `Outer` class? Would it be possible to replace with `Inner<TInnerItem>` in the rest of the code instead?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think I understand why I can't do this type of conversion in C#. Here, I am basically interested in solutions on how to solve the reference problem: Make the inner generic collection store a reference to the outer generic collection. 

In my code, both collections mostly act as base classes themselves. I'd then have specific implementations of Inner<>:
    DerivedInner : Inner<WhateverInnerItem>
and use the Outer<> as in:
    Outer<DerivedInner, WhateverInnerItem>