# Generic class and downcasting (typecasting)

Tags: c#, generics

```
public interface ISomeDTOInterface 
{
    ...
}

public class    SomeDTOClass : ISomeDTOInterface
{
    ...
}

public interface DataStoreChanges<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> data {get;}
    IEnumerable<Guid> removedItems {get;}
    IEnumerable<Guid> newItems {get;}
    IEnumerable<Guid> modifiedItems {get;}
}
```

now I have a method which expects

```
DataStoreChanges<ISomeDTOInterface>
```

, so I try to pass an instance of 
`DataStoreChanges<SomeDTOClass>`, 
which generates a type error. It wont let me downcast to the interface:)
so whats wrong here.

Comment: Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847538/nested-generic-collections-how-to-implement-reference-from-item-to-container

Comment: first interface is the data exchange contract type. and the class is its Json implementation of it in the UI. UI uses the concrete type to deserialize the json string into an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# 4, you can make the interface covariant. To do this, change the interface declaration to:

```
public interface DataStoreChanges<out T>
```

Otherwise, you can make the method generic and add the relevant type constraint.

```
void SomeMethod<T> (DataStoreChanges<T> x)  where T : ICommonInterface
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works. Now I remember reading about all that covariance and that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You're having issues because by default you're not specifying that the method should allow a more derived type of T, in that sense its not covariant.  By changing your interface definition to:

```
public interface DataStoreChanges<out T>
```

This will allow covariance.

If that is not possible, I guess you could also use a generic constraint on `where T : ICommonInterface`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are lacking type constrains - but could you actually add the non-compiling code?

```
where T:ICommonInterface
```

But this is just an educated guess based on your other information.

Comment: I cannot add that constraint. It is going to be different in each case, I am going to be using a common interface for each data object to exchange data between application layers.